# Constrain the movement of rigid bodies to two axes

Tags: physics, constraints

Is there a way to have an object, a ball for example, fall down and bounce up, using rigid body dynamics, but with its movement locked to two axes? So basically that would make for a 2 dimensional simulation.

I tried using a generic rigid body constraint but that doesn't seem to do anything when I lock a single axis. Now I'm faking it by putting the ball between four planes, in a box basically. Although there should be a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a copy location constraint on the ball to some other objects x, y coordinate.

[image]
*Ball locked to bounce on plane origin (0, 0, 0)*

[image]